# How to use Moodle REST API Call mod_data_add_entry (and parameters)?

Tags: rest, api, post, moodle

I'm trying to set up a webpage that communicates with a Moodle page. I need different data from a database activity and want to create new entries. Note that I am not talking about the SQL database in BG, it is the activity database in courses.

The information should be retrieved/transferred via the REST API, an HTML POST Request. My problem is that I don't know how to add a new record to the database activity because I cannot transfer the data array. Only the first parameter given appears in my database.

E.g. i tried ...&wsfunction=mod_data_add_entry&databaseid=10&data[0][fieldid]=66&data[0][value]=12&data[1][fieldid]=67&data[1][value]=test

And many other combinations. Always only the first parameter is shown in the database.
The docs tell me this (Pseudocode):

```
//The fields data to be created
list of ( 
 object {
  fieldid int   //The field id.
  subfield string  Default to "" //The subfield name (if required).
  value string   //The contents for the field always JSON encoded.
 } 
)
```

Alternatively:

```
REST (POST parameters)

data[0][fieldid]= int
data[0][subfield]= string
data[0][value]= string
```

I cannot find anywhere else something called a "subfield".
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found it. You have to put your values in "", unless they are not a number. Seems like there is a connection with this special activity because you don't have to do it elsewhere.